# How can notifications sounds play from application resources?

Tags: android

I have used the following code: the `mp3` is saved in the mobile sdcard.

```
notification.sound =  Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/File/sdcard/introduction_file.mp3");
```

do you know how a `mp3` file can be played as an application recources and not from the sdcard?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

See [android guide for playing from raw resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html#playraw).